# Blazor WebAssembly with Authentication (Individual accounts) with sql server by default

Tags: authentication, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to create asp blazor with authentication project.

But seems that can't change from sql to mongoDB.

I don't need to use sql in authentication because I'm planing to use mongoDb in the whole application.

Anyway to change sql to mongoDB in blazor authentication?

They are using this:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Comment: I was only just reading this hope it helps. https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-identity-mongodb/?fbclid=IwAR0EwdQ0AnG3agzs1guMpcyfWR0zwN4lQ0iOE5B8EmQ_xFSVMh3eFn3TpyA

Comment: @BrianParker Thank you! I'll try it.